# Export MySQL Data to a PDF Form using PHP or XML

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdf

i have a problem on a project I'm working on. I have to create an HTML Form that inserts data in MySQL and then prints the data on an existing PDF Form Template in pre-defined fields. My Problem comes in with the PDF. I've created my form and it inserts the data into MySQL now i need to get that data into the PDF Form. I have looked at FPDF adn Numerous others non of them do what i want.

Comment: A little bit overkill, but use a template engine like twig or smarty to render an html equivalent of the pdf, and then use mpdf (I prefer it even though slower) to print that html into a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an create PDF with active fields in it. Such PDFs can be opened in Reader and we can insert data in text fields. Those can be generated by PDF create tools(Google it). So after creating this tyoe of PDF form you can use an application `PDFTK` to fill those PDF form with values we post in a form. After filling those data we can crete a normal un-editable copy of pdf to download

Comment: I already have a PDF Form with interactive fields that i created with Adobe Acrobat Pro. The problem is I dont know how to Populate those fields with the MySQL Data collected. The idea is that once the user clicks submit it will insert the data into the database and populate the PDF at the same time so that the user thinks he gets a PDF form by just filling in the fields in the form.

Comment: I have done this a long time ago I still have the code. I have to read the whole code to understand what I have done
So please Take a look at my 
[github](https://github.com/sreevisakh/php-pdf)
It worked once so you will get all necessary code there

Comment: Thank so much. im checking out the link now. will post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any PDF creation tool (FPDF, Zend, TCPDF) to create the form using XY, or first convert the template to PHP and generate it on the fly.

Just query the DB for the proper fields and positions.

Comment: how do i do this? how do i find the XY co-ords? I have the template with field already set up how do i populate those fields?